# Regex for sqoop deamon logs

Tags: regex, hadoop, sqoop

I'm trying to create a regex for Sqoop logs.

Below is the log :

```
> Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12- 
1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
18/12/06 07:03:04 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
18/12/06 07:03:05 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
18/12/06 07:03:05 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
18/12/06 07:03:05 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
18/12/06 07:03:05 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
18/12/06 07:03:06 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM ROH319P4 AS t WHERE 1=0
18/12/06 07:03:06 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/92b93a5009481a238e86271708bb80e0/ROH319P4.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
18/12/06 07:03:10 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/92b93a5009481a238e86271708bb80e0/ROH319P4.jar
18/12/06 07:03:10 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of ROH319P4
18/12/06 07:03:10 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
18/12/06 07:03:11 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
18/12/06 07:03:11 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-27-88-6.ap-south-1.compute.internal/172.27.88.6:8032
18/12/06 07:03:14 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation
18/12/06 07:03:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
18/12/06 07:03:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1536239303820_0582
18/12/06 07:03:15 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1536239303820_0582
18/12/06 07:03:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ip-172-27-88-6.ap-south-1.compute.internal:20888/proxy/application_1536239303820_0582/
18/12/06 07:03:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1536239303820_0582
18/12/06 07:03:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1536239303820_0582 running in uber mode : false
18/12/06 07:03:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/12/06 07:03:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
18/12/06 07:03:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1536239303820_0582 completed successfully
18/12/06 07:03:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30

File System Counters
    FILE: Number of bytes read=0
    FILE: Number of bytes written=189523
    FILE: Number of read operations=0
    FILE: Number of large read operations=0
    FILE: Number of write operations=0
    HDFS: Number of bytes read=87
    HDFS: Number of bytes written=4997
    HDFS: Number of read operations=4
    HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
    HDFS: Number of write operations=2
Job Counters 
    Launched map tasks=1
    Other local map tasks=1
    Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=742431
    Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
    Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=4057
    Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=4057
    Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=23757792
Map-Reduce Framework
    Map input records=38
    Map output records=38
    Input split bytes=87
    Spilled Records=0
    Failed Shuffles=0
    Merged Map outputs=0
    GC time elapsed (ms)=62
    CPU time spent (ms)=1260
    Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=295165952
    Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=7060725760
    Total committed heap usage (bytes)=340262912
File Input Format Counters 
    Bytes Read=0
File Output Format Counters 
    Bytes Written=4997
18/12/06 07:03:28 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 4.8799 KB in 17.1259 seconds (291.781 bytes/sec)
18/12/06 07:03:28 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 38 records.
```

The regex that I have tried creating :

> ^(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2})\s+(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2})\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)$

So my aim is to fetch lines with the format like :

> 18/12/06 07:03:06 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce

Can anyone please help me out in figuring out the regex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex was almost correct, except following,

1. First `\d{4}` should have been `\d{2}` as year is only having two digits. If you think it can have 4 to 2 digits, you could use `\d{2,4}`
2. `/` character needs to be escaped in regex like this `\/`
3. Instead of `.` you need to use `:` as your time is colon separated. Although `.` will match any character and even colon, but I think you should better be precise and use `:`

So you updated regex becomes this which matches successfully the lines in your log files,

```
^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)$
```

**[Check here](https://regex101.com/r/84afy9/1)**

And if you don't want capture groups, it becomes better with non-capture groups,

```
^(?:\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})\s+(?:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(?:\S+)\s+(?:\S+)\s+(?:.*)$
```

**[Without groups](https://regex101.com/r/84afy9/2)**

Comment: Thanks Pushpesh, I'm trying to fetch these records in Apache PIG, so the regex definition is a little different.  '^(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{2})\\s+(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(.*)$'    ....Thanks alot man once again. It worked.

Comment: Pleased to help Nagesh :)